# django query return primary key related column values

Tags: mysql, django

I'm new to using databases and making django queries to get information.

If I have a table with id as the primary key, and ages and height as other columns, what query would bring me back a dictionary of all the ids and the related ages?

For instance if my table looks like below:

```
special_id | ages | heights
1          | 5    | x1
2          | 10   | x2
3          | 15   | x3
```

I'd like to have a key-value pair like {special_id: ages} where special_id is also the primary key.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - Query results as 'associative' dict?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781242/django-query-results-as-associative-dict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_json(request):
    result = MyModel.objects.all().values('id', 'ages')  # or simply .values() to get all fields
    result_list = list(result)  # important: convert the QuerySet to a list object
    return JsonResponse(result_list, safe=False)
```

You will get classic:

```
{field_name: field_value}
```

And if you want `{field_value: field_value}` you can do:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_json(request):
    result = MyModel.objects.all()
    a = {}
    for item in result:
        a[item.id] = item.age
    return JsonResponse(a)
```